# Bootstrap 3 run slowly in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, twitter-bootstrap-3

I load plain [Bootstrap starter app](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/) (minified css and js) on PhoneGap (latest version, 3.0.0). Somehow it takes 8-10 seconds just to load the application (run on Samsung S3). Does anyone encounter the same issue? How to improve?

I believe it's not PhoneGap nor my Samsung S3 issue as plain HTML without Bootstrap load very fast.

Comment: Are all of your resource files being loaded locally? Or are you linking them to a CDN?

Comment: All resources are in local

Comment: Have you looked into loading your files with a module loader such as RequireJS?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the javascript? That's the only thing that really would be slowing it down I think.

Comment: Without any javascript, it is slightly faster. But still 6 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the manifest
- If you use webview:

  webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH); and webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

Comment: Where to put AndroidManifest.xml in phonegap?
I use server remote build

Comment: AFAIK Phonegap remote build don't have manifest file, try the second option of webview settings.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need phonegap? 
I made some applications with cordova + bootstrap (v3) and the applications start in less than 3 seconds.

Be sure that your resource files being loaded locally.

Comment: This does **not** answer the question.

Comment: Of course it's not. But it's a good **workaroud** to the problem. I used _phonegap_ and _ionic_ for other project and sometime you don't need other framework to build a simple application.